# how to add url parameters in ElasticSearch DeleteByQuery java API?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-java-api

I am using Elasticsearch version 2.3.1

I want to implement Deletebyquery of ES in java

Es have docs for that https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

This doc stats that In deletebyquery request we can have a params like wait_for_completion=false , wait_for_active_shards , etc

This is fine for curl request, But my problem is I want to implement the same using java api, with that  wait_for_completion flag set.

My java code for Deletebyquery in java

```
DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder deleteRequest = DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(esType, DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE)
        .setIndices(index)
        .setTypes(type);
deleteRequest.setQuery(boolQuery);
DeleteByQueryResponse resp = deleteRequest.get();
```

I want to know where I can add wait_for_completion flag in java api request, kindly advice me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document link provided in the OP is for the latest version of elasticsearch.
 Elasticsearch 2.3 supports DeleteByQuery only via a [plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/delete-by-query-usage.html). 
 The external plugin does not have `wait_for_completion` option.
 The feature was re-introduced in 5.x.

Comment: How to add the query string parameters such as size , timeout in Deletebyquery query request? its mentioned in doc but do not know how to add in java api! https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/delete-by-query-usage.html